# FQL page_fan query to filter results of only one page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-page

I have a fql query like this:

```
SELECT uid,page_id,type,profile_section,created_time FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ;
```

Is there any way to get only the results where page_id = XXXXXX?
Because the page_id is not indexable.. and i was hoping for a way to filter it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found a great solution that works for me to get friends that are not pagefans.

```
$facebook_result = $this->facebook->api(array(
    'method' => 'fql.multiquery',
    'queries' => array(
        'friends_liking_page' => 'SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND page_id = ' . $page_id,
        'result' => 'SELECT uid, name, pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() AND NOT (uid2 IN (SELECT uid FROM #friends_liking_page)))'
    )
));
```